# Make a GtkHeaderBar application using Glade

Tags: user-interface, glade

I'm trying to develop a Gtk application using glade, but got stuck with creating GtkHeaderBars.

In this video, it says, the feature of HeaderBars would already be implemented in Glade: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sw3Gn7Ms76E
But neither the option for Client side decorations, nor the actual Headerbar widget seem to exist in the latest Glade version (3.18.3)

Is there a workaround for that?

I know, you can code these things by hand, but I would like to intergrate it into my Glade workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can use JHBUILD (https://developer.gnome.org/jhbuild/stable/) to build the current git- or development-version of Glade. The video was probably done the same way.